# statistical data to HTML tables (filter/sort/aggregate) and charts using django

Tags: django, django-statistics

I have lots of tables with statistical data (environment related) and wondering if there are any existing django app that will let me quickly produce charts i.e. sort/filter type of functionality. is there any short cuts..

This data will only be used during a temporary event for analyst, so it feels like a lot of tedious task to deal with..

Thanks for any pointer. Google doesn't provide much help thought you guys might know such app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to do this on the frontend using a javascript plugin. See the jQuery plugins [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/) for sorting tables and [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) for generating charts.